# Human body emits Radiation

Tags: thermodynamics

Human being emits which type of waves 
and how to find that waves 
any possibility to detect this waves by 
Using sensors

Comment: There's plenty of info on this out on the web. Tell us what what aspect of your internet review you don't understand, and we can help you with that.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/142971/is-a-suit-that-hides-a-soldiers-heat-signature-fundamentally-possible

Comment: If humans are blackbodies, we emit this much: $I=\sigma T^4$ ($I$ is radiation intensity in $[\mathrm{W/m^2}]$.)

Comment: see also: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/99254/, http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/89477/, and http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/89269/

Answer (score 3):

Because of our body temperature, humans emit radiation in the [Infrared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared) range. At $37^\circ C$, humans emit infrared radiation primarily at a wavelength of $12\mu m$ or $0.000012m$. A large number of detectors can be used to measure this emission. This radiation emission is how heat-sensitive cameras can see people in the dark. There are many other examples as well of technologies that are used to sense, measure, or quantify the IR emission of humans.